# Numbering sections independent of chapters numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

Is it a way to create a document in such a way that the numbering of the sections is independent of that of the chapters?

e.g.:

```
Chapter 1
   section 1
   section 2
Chapter 2
   section 3
   section 4
   section 5
Chapter 3
   section 6
   section 7
```

Comment: Yes, of course, this is possible. `\usepackage{remreset}
 
\makeatletter
  \@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
\makeatother` will prevent the automatic resetting of section counters if the chapter number is increased.

Comment: Add the following to your preamble: `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithout{section}{chapter}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer With `remreset`, sections will still feature the chapter prefix.

Comment: @lockstep: I know, therefore I have changed the counter formatting additionally in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{remreset}

\makeatletter
  \@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\section{Third}
\chapter{Second}
\section{Fourth}
\section{Fifth}
\section{Sixth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Name: You could use of course also lockstep's proposition