# Continuous numbering of the sections without external packages

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I would like a numbering of the sections as below. I have previously asked this question in [Numbering sections independent of chapters numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207968/39306). An excellent answer was provided https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207971/39306 using **remreset** package. Also a more general solution is given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28334/39306 using **chngcntr** package.

> I am wondering if there is a solution without the use of any external package?

```
Chapter 1
   section 1
   section 2
Chapter 2
   section 3
   section 4
   section 5
Chapter 3
   section 6
   section 7
```

Here is my file:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\section{Third}
\chapter{Second}
\section{Fourth}
\section{Fifth}
\section{Sixth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is wrong with `remreset`? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you should always avoid my packages

Comment: @ChristianHupfer your solution was excellent, and anything was wrong with it. I was just curious to know an answer without using an external package.

Comment: @Name: I did not check that it was a solution of mine :D

Comment: Look at the package file, it is not very complicated ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\cl@chapter{}
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\section{Third}
\chapter{Second}
\section{Fourth}
\section{Fifth}
\section{Sixth}

\end{document}
```