# Memoir TOC, Biblatex and \refsegment are not aligning the "References" as a subsection but a section instead

Tags: biblatex, memoir

Following on from my previous lab-book [question about numbering appendices but not `\mainmatter` chapters in a `memoir` TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/654013/273733), I do not know where to begin with modifying the references section (per section) on the TOC. An image is probably a better descriptor:

[image]

I am using the `refsegment` option of `biblatex` so that each "day" has its own independent reference section and then at the end, a complete bibliography. I am not sure why the "References" are aligning as if they are a `section` rather than `subsection` and I do not know whether this is a `biblatex` solution or `memoir` solution, hence the tags.

How can I align the "References" as if they were a subsection of the previous section rather then appearing to be sections, is this possible please?

I will admit I have tried little so my apologies for that, I do not know if it is a `biblatex` solution or `memoir` solution and I cannot profess great knowledge over either. I have a feeling it is due to the `section+` option passed to `biblatex` but I could not be sure either way.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,refsegment=section+,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setsecnumdepth{subparagraph}
\settocdepth{subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\part{2022}
\chapter{August}
Text

\newpage
\section{\today}
Text \cite{sigfridsson}
\subsection{Testing}
Text
\subsection{Testing}
Text
\subsubsection{Test}
Text

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibliography]

\newpage
\section{11/11/11}
Text
\subsection{Test}
Text
\subsubsection{Test}
\cite{murray}

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibliography]

\backmatter
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I am compiling the MWE with:

```
% arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I regret that I have not tried much with this but I genuinely do not know what to try or which to try first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest "regular" sectioning level in `memoir` is `\chapter`. So that's what the standard `bibliography` heading uses. `subbibliography` is one level below that, so `\section`. If you want a `\subsection`-level heading, you have to define your own `subsubbibliography` heading.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,refsegment=section+,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\defbibheading{subsubbibliography}[\refname]{%
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \ifmemoirbibintoc
    {\phantomsection
     \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}
    {}}

\setsecnumdepth{subparagraph}
\settocdepth{subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\part{2022}
\chapter{August}
Text

\newpage
\section{\today}
Text \cite{sigfridsson}
\subsection{Testing}
Text
\subsection{Testing}
Text
\subsubsection{Test}
Text

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subsubbibliography]

\newpage
\section{11/11/11}
Text
\subsection{Test}
Text
\subsubsection{Test}
\cite{murray}

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subsubbibliography]

\backmatter
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: ToC of the document with "References" shown as subsection.]

The `refsegment` option has nothing to do with this.